Bone rotates strangely when using basic human rig
When I animated two bones (each using quaternion rotation) rotating while mirroring one side using the flip option (x-axis mirror), the side that I keyframed after rotating the other ended up turning in a weird direction and I haven't found any way to fix it yet.



hello please share the armature with the animation you show

@moonboots the armature is the built-in basic human armature in blender, but here is an image anyway:

This is likely bad rotation interpolation caused by gimbal lock. You can alleviate the issue by running an euler filter on the rotation curves, from the graph editor, in the curves menu. If it doesn't help, you should change the rotation order of the hand controller to something else (in the sidebar, under transform).

ah, I should've clarified that I was using quaternion rotation.

In that case, you might have moved the WXYZ curves out of sync. This can break the slerp (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp)
